# ConnectivityManager missing when a VPN is connected

Tags: android, kotlin, internet-connection

i have a function that returns connectivity state of device and it works fine all the time except when device is connected to the VPN , it gives false Positive when network is not available

```
    fun isConnected(): Boolean {
        var result = false
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val actNw =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(networkCapabilities) ?: return false
            result = when {
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN) -> true

                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            connectivityManager.run {
                connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                    result = when (type) {
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET -> true
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN -> true
                        else -> false
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that an app that does not have access to the VPN is showing that it has connectivity when in fact, there is no connectivity?

Comment: when device is connected to internet with VPN if we disconnect the internet like turning off the wifi and not turn off the VPN its going to say that device is still connected to the internet, that is what i mean about false positive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to confirm that your network has internet, you can't only test `connectivityManager.activeNetwork` and `actNw.hasTransport`.

`connectivityManager.activeNetwork` will return the VPN as it is the active network whether it has internet or not. `actNw.hasTransport` just lets you know the transport of the connection. If you don't care about the transport, you can probably remove that code completely.

What you should check for are [NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) and [NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED).

[NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)

> Indicates that this network should be able to reach the internet.

[NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)

> Indicates that connectivity on this network was successfully
> validated. For example, for a network with NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET, it
> means that Internet connectivity was successfully detected.

Therefore what you really need is to check if the active network has both of those capabilities to determine if you are connected to a network with internet connectivity.

```
actNw.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
actNw.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
```

Comment: this not working in case of connected to vpn but internet is not available

Comment: If so, then something else is wrong as `NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED` should only ever be on a network which is successfully able to reach the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Did You Try to add this:

```
actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN) -> true
```

Comment: yes i tried it before ,that actually was the cause of the problem at the first place but removing it didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, when VPN is connected and WiFi was OFF, still `NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED` and `TRANSPORT_VPN` was returning true.

instead of `connectivityManager.activeNetwork` use `connectivityManager.allNetworks`

if WiFi toggle is ON and connected to a network `connectivityManager.allNetworks` will return 2 networks else it will return 1 network as the VPN is the active default network.